# Display just one post from a loop of 5 posts?

Tags: php, array

Let's say I have this Query to which I fetch all my WP posts and then use PHP to filter out even further:

```
<?php    

$posts = get_posts(array(


    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'type',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'campaign' ),
            ),
    
        ),  
    
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => 999999999999999999,
    'orderby'               => 'rand',
));

        
if( $posts): ?>
            
            <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata( $post ) ?>

// Filter out users with funds with PHP
<?php
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$advertiser_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
$advertiser_userfunds=get_user_meta( $advertiser_id, 'userfunds' , true );
if ($advertiser_userfunds > 0):?>

//5 posts left in the loop after filtering out users with funds

<?php endif;?>      



<?php endforeach; ?>
    
 <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

So let's say I'm left with a loop of 5 posts now.

My question is, is there any way to show just 1 post?

It can be in a random order, or simply showing first or last post from the loop?

I know there's a php code `if in_array()`. Maybe I could implement this somehow?

Desperately need help.

Comment: Are you looking for the [`break`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) keyword?

Comment: Solved it, anyway, thanks for your effort, Ivan!

Comment: `orderby => 'rand'` is [generally](https://docs.wpvip.com/technical-references/code-review/vip-warnings/#h-order-by-rand) a [bad idea](https://wpengine.com/support/about-order-by-rand/), for what it's worth.

Comment: I know, but that's the only solution that is actually doing what I want right now. But, I know it does take a lot of processes and slows down when more posts will be published. Will do the job for now, will think of the other randomizer solution later.

Comment: If you only want `1` post, why are you asking for `999999999999999999`? This query is extremely slow/expensive

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by inserting this:

```
<?php if (in_array($counter, array(0)) ) :?>
// show content
<?php $counter++; endif;?>
```

The above basically displays only 1 post that is first in the array.

In case anyone needs to solve a problem like this.

Comment: I could see why you used a custom counter (in the `if ($advertiser_userfunds > 0)` block), but then why not just do `<?php if ( 0 === $counter ) :?>` instead of `<?php if (in_array($counter, array(0)) ) :?>`? And btw, the question is actually a generic PHP question and should instead be asked on Stack Overflow. 

Comment: Also, variables need to be defined before attempting to use them, so make sure you define `$counter`, e.g. `$counter = 0;` before the `foreach( $posts as $post )`